# Play wav file with libvlc will lost the begining or end

Tags: delphi, wav, libvlc

I use libvlc to play my simple wav file.
i found that when i use libvlc 3.0.2-3.0.4, libvlc will lost the end of the wav.
if i use libvlc 3.0.9-3.0.11, libvlc will lost the begining of the wav.

but if i use vlcplayer to play the same wav file. the player plays complete.

what's the difference between the vlcplayer and the libvlc?

i use libvlc and vlcplayer in windows 32bit.

```
procedure TVlcWapper.Play(MediaFileName : string);
var
  MediaHandle : Plibvlc_media_t;
begin
  MediaHandle := libvlc_media_new_path(FInstance, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(MediaFileName)));

  if Assigned(MediaHandle) then
  begin
    libvlc_media_player_set_media(FMediaPlayer, MediaHandle);

    // now no need the vlc media, free it
    libvlc_media_release(MediaHandle);
    MediaHandle := nil;

    libvlc_media_player_play(FMediaPlayer);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you try with LibVLC sample Delphi program at https://wiki.videolan.org/Using_libvlc_with_Delphi/

Comment: Yes, i tried the officail sample just now, and get the same result. I have a sample wav file that show the problem. https://mega.nz/#!TTYmBZLY!95Jv_6uAMNmFShU4Zg1NLQx4PLvxCqpk4UlhguqE6n0

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't happen with all wav files?

Comment: for the 3.0.9-3.0.11, it looks like more affacted to the shorter wav files less than 100k

Comment: Maybe you'd get a better help from VideoLAN forums at https://forum.videolan.org/

Comment: how do you know the beginning or end is lost? Please share that code